# Mesos-Marathon docker

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

Is there a way to restart previously active marathon docker container using marathon GUI. I tried suspend and start using scale option but it's creating a new container rather than restarting the previously active container.

Could some one help me if there is a way to start and stop docker containers from marathon GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible and that's by design. The idea is that of immutable infrastructure: when you have a Marathon app that, say, consists of one task (let's say a Docker container) and you change something, for example an environment variable, you launch a new container with said properties. You never change and hence never re-use an already running container.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote/mark as correct, this is the way to show others here …